# Errors while installing a module

Tags: node.js, bots

So I tried following the guide [here](https://github.com/andrewda/node-steam-guide/tree/master/Chapter%201%20-%20Basics/Chapter%201.2%20-%20Prerequisites), but when I try to install the module these errors pop up:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\james\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\james\package.json'
npm WARN james No description
npm WARN james No repository field.
npm WARN james No README data
npm WARN james No license field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should run `npm init -y` command. This creates package.json file for you. Then you can install any module.